# Sort table based on value provided

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if there is a way to sort a table based on provided value using javascript.

For example, if I have a table as below:

```
id      name      team    
1       doe       red
2       dee       blue
3       daa       yellow
4       doo       green
5       duu       green
```

Let say I have button named green. If I click the button green I want to display the data with green first. So the result that I want is:

```
id      name      team    
4       doo       green
5       duu       green
1       doe       red
2       dee       blue
3       daa       yellow
```

Thank you! Appreciate it :)

Comment: what kind of table? is this a JSON object or an HTML table?

Comment: Yes, there is undoubtedly a way. However you've provided absolutely no code showing us what you have to work with and more importantly, what you've tried.

Comment: HTML table. I am sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: @j08691 Sorry. All I have right now is sorting desc and asc. I just cannot think of a way to do what I want to do, so I figured I should ask. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic for your requirement:

```
    var x = [].slice.call(document.getElementById("myTable").rows);
    var search_rows = [];
    var non_search_rows = [];

    var search_text = "green";      // replace it with button text
    var cell_index = 2;             // replace it with column index containing data

    x.forEach(function(row){
        if (row.cells[cell_index].innerHTML === search_text) search_rows.push(row);
        else non_search_rows.push(row);
      })

    var rows_in_order = search_rows.concat(non_search_rows);
    var d = document.createDocumentFragment();

    rows_in_order.forEach(function(row)
      {
      d.appendChild(row);
      });

    document.getElementById("myTable").tBodies[0].appendChild(d);
```